# Determine if Friend is in a Friends List

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

So I can get a list of friends via
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends
and a list of friends lists via
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friendlists.

Is there any way to determine if a friend is in a certain list or to get all friends in a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. According to the API v2.0 changelog: "The permission read_friendlists no longer allows you to read the list of friends in a friendlist, but only lets you access the name of the list. This is useful for people building custom audience selectors when posting stories."

Comment: Is there a way to find a friend that is NOT in any list?  I want to make sure all my friends are in one of my lists.

Comment: No it is not possible in any automatic way